# Serve RSA & EC certificate in same istio gateway

Tags: kubernetes, istio

Due to a mix of legacy devices and newer devices I want to serve both RSA and EC certificates for a service that is exposed via HTTPS using the same DNS name and on the same port.

I have followed the official guide for secure gateways of istio mentioned here: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/#configure-a-mutual-tls-ingress-gateway. Unfortunately it doesn't mention whether it's possible at all to configure multiple certificates for a single secure gateway.

According to https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/security/ssl envoy supports certificate selection based on the advertised cipher suites of the client connecting to the service.

Can istio generate a envoy configuration with a DownstreamTlsContext using two certificates? If yes how would I go about configuring this in istio / the involved k8s Secrets?

I'm aware that I can passthrough the TLS traffic to a pod (running e.g. nginx) and do the TLS offloading within that pod, but as of now I'd like to keep my cluster as homogenous as possible.

Comment: There is older [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7658) about multiple certificates in gateway, take a look. About DownstreamTlsContext as istio is based on envoy it might be possible that you could achieve that with [envoy filter](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/), but I couldn't find any example with that.

Comment: @jt97 Thank you for the idea. The envoy filter would probably have to patch the `DownstreamTlsContext` and add another configuration to `tlsCertificateSdsSecretConfigs` for a second set of certificate/key material. Might be quite a challenge to do that. I'll give it a go.